# Sed using regular expression

Tags: unix, sed

I want to extract substring **-[GCDAsyncSocketPreBuffer dealloc]** from the output of the following command:

```
echo "123 | 2013-12-24 | OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.1 | Thread 4 Crashed: 7 com.apple.test.test 0x00000001053fdef3 -[GCDAsyncSocketPreBuffer dealloc] + 64" | sed 's/\[.*\]/\1\p'
```

I want to reformat the output to look like this:

**123 | 2013-12-24 | OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.1 | -[GCDAsyncSocketPreBuffer dealloc]**

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `sed` solution (OSX users: replace `-r` with `-E`):

```bash
in="123 | 2013-12-24 | OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.1 | Thread 4 Crashed: 7 com.\
apple.test.test 0x00000001053fdef3 -[GCDAsyncSocketPreBuffer dealloc] + 64"

sed -r 's/\|[^|]+([-+]\[[^]]+\]).*$/\| \1/' <<<"$in"
```

Note that this expression will also correctly detect `'+[...]'` substrings.

---

- `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F '[|]|-\\[|]' '{ print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "| -[" $5 "]" }' <<<"$in"
```

---

- If you have `gawk`, you can provide a more flexible solution via `gensub()` - as in the `sed` solution, the following will also match `'+[...]'` substrings.

```bash
gawk '{ print gensub("[|][^|]+([-+]\\[[^]]+\\]).*$", "| \\1", "1") }' <<<"$in"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only `-[GCDAsyncSocketPreBuffer dealloc]`, then use this sed command:

```
sed 's/.*\(-\[[^]]\+\]\).*/\1/g'
```

If you want the

```
123 | 2013-12-24 | OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.1 | -[GCDAsyncSocketPreBuffer dealloc]
```

Then this might work for you:

```
sed 's/\(.*-\[[^]]\+\]\).*/\1/g'
```

Comment: The first command works (on Linux; on OSX you don't have the `+` quantifier, so you'd need to use `sed 's/.*\(-\[[^]]\{1,\}\]\).*/\1/g'`), but the 2nd one doesn't (strings is output as is).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -r 's/^(([^|]+\|){3}).*(-[^]]+]).*/\1 \3/'
```

If you don't have `-r` option,

```
sed 's/^\(\([^|]\+|\)\{3\}\).*\(-[^]]\+]\).*/\1 \3/'
```

**Test:**

`echo "123 | 2013-12-24 | OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.1 | Thread 4 Crashed: 7 com.apple.test.test 0x00000001053fdef3 -[GCDAsyncSocketPreBuffer dealloc] + 64" | sed -r 's/^(([^|]+\|){3}).*(-[^]]+]).*/\1 \3/`'

Comment: +1 for the `-r` version (OSX users: use `-E`), but the non-`r` version doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*|\).*\(-.*]\).*/\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/|[^[|]*//;s/]/*/]/'
```

remove  part between last | and [ than the end after ]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (on Linux: `sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to 's'`).

Comment: add -posix with GNU sed, GNU is using | as OR, not other version like mine on AIX that have a Reduce RegEx syntax.

Comment: Even after adding `--posix` I get the same error: the problem is the 3rd segment, `]/`, at the end of the 2nd `s` command: it gets interpreted as a regex option. Overall, I'm not clear on how your command is supposed to work: the 1st `s` command eliminates just the *2nd* pipe segment from the original string, whereas what you want is to eliminate the _first 3_ to be left with the 4th, which contains the substring of interest. I'm unclear on what the 2nd `s` command is trying to achieve ; if we drop the 3rd segment, all you do is replace one `]` with a literal `*` (at least with `--posix`).

Comment: error interface keyboard - chair, i wrongly type ]/* instead of ].* in last s/, sorry